# XCB key inputs interception?

Tags: linux, input, keyboard, xlib, xcb

What is the code for intercept key inputs on XCB protocol?

I can't find anything on the XCB documentation for that purpose (or i can't see the right piece of doc/code).
I use Python, but a C example can be good for understand the code.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

[xcb events](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/)

Takes the time to read all this page and then focus on the keyboard events.
At the end, there is a full example of an xcb application save the code in the_name_of_the_source_file.c (for example)

Compile it with:

```
gcc -lxcb -o the_name_of_the_application the_name_of_the_source_file.c
```

Comment: Thanks @cedlemo but this is just for my window. I need to intercept all keys (with ability to block) regardless of window. Is this possible?